# Load balancing MessageQ (ActiveMQ)

Tags: asynchronous, activemq-classic, message-queue

This is my scenario..

1) A REST based web service (Say X) takes in requests and puts it into ActiveQ
2) There is a listener on the other side of the Q that will read and process the message. This is async

I decided to go with ActiveMQ. 
But trying to find a solution where I can Q and the Q listeners scalable.

1) I have many instances of X running. Hence there are multiple prodders to the Q.
2) Ordering is important to me.
3) Since my REST service is session less, I don't have a way to tag a bunch of requests with the same message ID.
4) Now if I use a single Q, it works fine..

But I want to scale it up and use multiple Q and multiple Q consumers without compromising on the order.

Can someone suggest me a solution to this problem?

Thanks much,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve ordering of messages there are 2 ways defined in activeMQ

1)MessageGroups based on JMSXGroupID

2)Exclusive Consumer

Message groups are more useful than Exclusive consumer,as internally Exclusive Consumer only uses one consumer at a time,but in case of that consumer failure it connects to other consumer.

You can read the ActiveMQ documentation for the same here

- http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-preserve-order-of-messages.html

hope this helps!
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

We can use following kind of connection URL to utilize ActiveMQ load....

```
failover://(tcp://192.nnn.nn.nn:61616,tcp://192.nnn.nn.nn:61616)?randomize=false
```

`randomize=true` will made message shuffles between two AciveMQ in active mode, rather not by just fail-over of ActiveMQ......

Complete reference for this can be found under the following Apache Site link....

http://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html

But Still high availability (i.e, cluster) configuration make things stable for your App although Apache must advance ActiveMQ High Availability, hence things can work smoother.

Although because of `KahaDB` restriction load balancing/fault tolerant configuration is restricted. The present Apache ActiveMQ High Availability configuration available in the following link.

http://activemq.apache.org/clustering.html

However `KahaDB` has file lock restriction, following tweaking/alternates ways of configuration can be done...

1)Shared File System Master Slave,- A shared file system such as a SAN
http://activemq.apache.org/shared-file-system-master-slave.html

2)JDBC Master Slave,- A Shared database
http://activemq.apache.org/jdbc-master-slave.html

3)Replicated LevelDB Store,- ZooKeeper Server
http://activemq.apache.org/replicated-leveldb-store.html

Over & above by having JCA connectors,- AS like JBoss, Weblogic, Websphere, Geronimo, Glassfish,- ActimeMQ patching as a kind of Resource Adapter can be done. And with Apache Camel (karaf), JBoss Fuse ESB kind of products HA & clustering of ActiveMQ can be done.